# replace part of first line in a multi line string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with multiple lines. I read the file using read_file and put the entire string into a scalar string.

My Sample file format,

```
From : test@gmail.com
To : test1@gmail.com
Subject : Test Mail
```

and so my string will be like this,

```
$mystring = "From : test@gmail.com\nTo : test1@gmail.com\nSubject : Test Mail"
```

These are template files already generated with random address in From and To field. I want to change the From field alone with the custom one as below,

```
$mystring = "From : user1@yahoo.com\nTo : test1@gmail.com\nSubject : Test Mail"
```

All I have to do is search and replace the From field in a multi line string using perl. I am new to perl and don't have great exposure to it.

Comment: So you say you want to change one line in one file. Why are you not using a text editor? Also, if you want to change one line, its a bad idea to read the entire file into a single string.

Comment: `perl -pe 's/^From\s*:\s*\K.*/user1\@yahoo.com/' input > output`

Comment: @TLP, Just for example I have mentioned it as one line change. If we pass From, To or Subject, we have to overwrite the value in template file and do the operations. Your solution works fine.. Can you explain the syntax here.

Comment: I've posted an answer with the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a file as template to create another file, you can use shell redirection along with the `-p` switch for Perl in a one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/^From\s*:\s*\K.*/user1\@yahoo.com/' input > output
```

This will apply the substitution `s/.../.../` to all lines in the file and print the output to file. The regex explanation:

- `^` match beginning of string
- `\s*` match whitespace 0 or more times
- `\K` keep what is left of this symbol
- `.*` match any character except newline 0 or more times

The `.*` will consume the rest of the line, and the `\K` escape will preserve the `From:` part, inserting the new email afterwards. Note that you need to escape the `@` character to prevent variable interpolation.

Comment: @mpapec, I thought accepting the solution will be enough. Anyway I have done it now.

Comment: I have one more query. Sometimes the From: field is not the first line of the string. I believe by default, it considers as a single line string. Can you tell me how to align the above regex considering the string as multiline string, so that we can check whether From: field starts at any line. Let me know if my comment is not so clear.

Comment: "The first line of the string" does not make sense. Either it is first line of the *file*, or at the start of the line. You should not use multiline strings, it just creates problems for you and you gain nothing.

Comment: Initially I thought 'From:' field should be the very first line of the string. But some other files are in different format. Say for example, $string = "Subject : Test Mail\n From : test@gmail.com\n"; In such case, I think I have to check whether 'From:' is at the beginning of a line. The anchor ^ checks only for the very start of the string assuming it considers the string as a single line string. Can you tell me how I have to align your regex for this case.

Comment: Yes, but why are you still reading the whole file into a variable? There is no point in doing that, it is bad. Stop using `File::Slurp` and your life will be a lot easier. If you really want `^` (and `$`) to also match newlines inside the string you can use the `m` modifier, i.e. `/^From:.../m`

Comment: That /m switch works well. I will also try the case without reading the entire file in one shot.

Comment: I don't understand why you do it, it only makes things harder for you. `open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Cannot open $file: $!"; while (<$fh>) { s/../.../; }` is as simple as it gets.

Comment: sorry for delayed response.. I can understand your concern. But it is not new script that I am going to write. I was just asked to do so in the existing script. I also understand that if we can avoid read_file(), we can do it in a simple manner..